# Why Facebook widget is in loading permanent circle?

Tags: html, facebook, web

On my website on the right side there is a Facebook page and looks like this:

[image]

Why doesn't it work? I simply set it like this:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v14.0" nonce="xv52lKjQ"></script>
    <div id="fb-box">
        <a href="" id="fb-icon"></a>
        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Skuteczna-Szko&#x142;a-P&#x142;ywania-Delfinek-1551938465126202/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="" data-height="" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/Skuteczna-Szko&#x142;a-P&#x142;ywania-Delfinek-1551938465126202/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Skuteczna-Szko&#x142;a-P&#x142;ywania-Delfinek-1551938465126202/">Skuteczna Szkoła Pływania Delfinek</a></blockquote></div>
    </div>
```

The same problem exist on Safari using iPhone. Why?

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me, in a private window. Check what the browser console has to say, perhaps some request gets blocked by an extension or something.

Comment: Thank you, for me on desktop browser in private tab also works. But on mobile device neither on normal nor private tab works. Is there any way to declare that I want to make it working on every tab?;)

Comment: No, because that is what it should do to begin with. But if any request gets blocked or something, there is little Facebook can do about it. Or you, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

1. Go to [Facebook Developers - Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) and configure the 'widget' with desired params.
2. As you change the parameters the preview should update & show. If it doesn't, try signing out.
3. Click "Get Code" beneath the preview. I used the JavaScript SDK method.
4. Copy & paste the first piece of code right after the < body > tag.
5. Copy & paste the second piece of code where the box should appear.

*Previous answer - leaving here for posterity / reference*

It is evidently an issue with Facebook that occurs **when the visitor is signed in to Facebook**. You and CBroe noted in the question's comments that it works in private tab, which behaves as though you are not signed in. Can you try signing out and see if it appears then?

There's more information on a Facebook Developers bug report, which was just marked as closed 8/26, although it still appears to be happening, for me anyway: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/584988619248795/

This other community thread has a work-around - look for Dave's comment: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1018223139108570/

Unfortunately the problem exists with Facebook and not something web developers have direct control of. Hopefully it is corrected soon.